# iOS 10 runtime missing

Tags: ios10, xcode8-beta6

I have the latest Xcode 8 beta 6 but I do not see any iOS 10 simulators. When I try to add one, I do not have the option to select iOS 10:

[image]
[image]

I tried removing and re-installing XCode 8 but it does not help.

The content of `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/` does indeed not show the iOS 10 runtime

```
ll /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/

drwxr-xr-x@ 4 root  wheel  136 May  5 08:53 iOS 7.1.simruntime
drwxrwxr-t  3 root  admin  102 Aug 22 13:51 iOS 8.4.simruntime
drwxrwxr-t  3 root  admin  102 Jul 12 08:30 iOS 9.3.simruntime
```

Comment: I get same output as you in each of 3 cases, except when I try to select a device from the list the simulators with iOS 10 are there

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue:

Basically iPhone 4S doesn't support iOS 10. Its architecture is unsupported.
So you can select any device from iPhone 5 onwards.

Please find screenshots below for reference:

[iPhone 4S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbZkM.png) & 
[iPhone 6S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeLAq.png)

Cheers!